# Disadvantages of using date_trunc

Tags: sql, postgresql

Several years ago I heard that truncate dates in sql is not a good practice. Is that true?

I need to get the value of a date type column from a table in "yyyy-MM-dd" format, the date is currently stored in the table with the "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" format

Comment: I do use this a lot in Oracle and don't see where is the problem. Do you think that is better to convert the timestamp into a date with the required pattern?

Comment: Yes, that is what I heard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's bad practice to store that in ***any*** kind of format, since you should store it as [`timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) not as `text` or `varchar`.

Then, to get the date, just cast:

```
SELECT col::date
```

Be aware that the "date" depends on your current **time zone** setting.

See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with using `date_trunc` under the right circumstances.

The main issue is where b-tree indexes are involved. If you have an index on `some_timestamp` and you search for `date_trunc('day', some_timestamp) = DATE '2012-01-01'`, PostgreSQL can't use the index.

(It could theoretically rewrite the `date_trunc` expression into an indexable range predicate, but it doesn't).

If you instead write:

```
some_timestamp >= DATE '2012-01-01' AND some_timestamp < DATE '2012-01-02'
```

then it's b-tree indexable. (Note that I intentionally did not use `BETWEEN` because it's both-inclusive).

It's sometimes useful to create an expression index, e.g.

```
create index blahindex on blahtable (date_trunc('day', some_timestamp));
```

but as each extra index has a maintenance cost it's better to just write your predicates to be easily usable with normal column indexes where possible.

Comment: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE